Flex Container cutting of item, which increases height on focus using outline
I am using following scss:
to have a row of buttons.
Working good. However in case of focus the single buttons size increases by a few pixels and it looks like parent flex container .form-buttons does not adapt the height and outline is cut of at the bottom due to that.
    .form-buttons {
        display: flex;
        gap: 5px;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .form-button {
        display: flex;
        gap: 5px;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-items:center;
        border-radius: 4px;
        min-height: 50px;
        padding: 0px 24px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-family: $font-family;
        &:focus ,&:focus-within{
            **outline: 2px solid $color-primary-link-default; 
            outline-offset: 1px;
        }

    } 

I ve tried setting a min-height for form-buttons, and that fixes for specific cases the issue, however I do not know in advance for all cases necessary min-height

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

can you please add so that we can address your problem.
